# Could not load class in Phone Gap

Tags: android, html, cordova

I am facing problem to run the function in phonegap like as alert box, splash screen. So if you have any solution please let me know. One code (index.html) is given in below for alert box application.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Notification Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for Cordova to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // Cordova is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Empty
    }

    // alert dialog dismissed
    function alertDismissed() {
        // do something
    }

    // Show a custom alertDismissed
    //
    function showAlert() {
        navigator.notification.alert(
            'You are the winner!',  // message
            alertDismissed,         // callback
            'Game Over',            // title
            'Done'                  // buttonName
        );
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p><a href="#" onclick="showAlert(); return false;">Show Alert</a></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm looking forward for valuable solutions.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace?

Comment: What is your problem exactly?

Comment: Gajotres: I want to simulate the code in Phonegap (index.html). But it shows that it could not load the class. So please tell me what can I do?

Comment: @asgoth: I'm running it from eclipse. So if you have any solution please let me know

Comment: so the error message is what exactly? Or does the console out put say "I am facing problem to run the function in phonegap like as alert box, splash screen"? :) Assuming you develop for android, what does logcat tell you?

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap phonegap functions in the deviceready function.

Notification Example

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for Cordova to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // Cordova is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Show a custom alertDismissed
    //
    function showAlert() {
        navigator.notification.alert(
            'You are the winner!',  // message
            alertDismissed,         // callback
            'Game Over',            // title
            'Done'                  // buttonName
        );
    }
    }

    // alert dialog dismissed
    function alertDismissed() {
        // do something
    }



    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p><a href="#" onclick="showAlert(); return false;">Show Alert</a></p>
  </body>
</html>
```